i am trying to display tamil and english video results together
my app is made with flutter and firebase and i have implemented sorting for search results based on search results in managevideos section but when i create a video with tamil title,description etc it won't display results and will just say string is not subtype of documentreference<object?>? in type cast i think its string comparison problem but i am don't undestand why ? logs show retrieval of relevant documents but it just doesn't show
Stream<List<UserPosts2Record>> _buildFilteredStream() {
    Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user_posts2');

    print('Building filtered stream for chip: $selectedChip');

    switch (selectedChip) {
      case 'All':
        query = query
            .where('post_user', isEqualTo: currentUserDisplayName)
            .orderBy('time_posted', descending: true);
        break;
      case 'Listed':
        query = query
            .where('post_user', isEqualTo: currentUserDisplayName)
            .where('isListed', isEqualTo: true);
        break;
      case 'Unlisted':
        query = query
            .where('post_user', isEqualTo: currentUserDisplayName)
            .where('isListed', isEqualTo: false);
        break;
      case 'Paid':
        query = query
            .where('post_user', isEqualTo: currentUserDisplayName)
            .where('is_Paid', isEqualTo: true);
        break;
      case 'Free':
        query = query
            .where('post_user', isEqualTo: currentUserDisplayName)
            .where('is_Paid', isEqualTo: false);
        break;
      case 'Short':
        query = query
            .where('post_user', isEqualTo: currentUserDisplayName)
            .where('videoduration', isLessThanOrEqualTo: 300);
        break;
      case 'Long':
        query = query
            .where('post_user', isEqualTo: currentUserDisplayName)
            .where('videoduration', isGreaterThan: 300);
        break;
      case 'Latest':
        query = query.orderBy('time_posted', descending: true);
        break;
      case 'Oldest':
        query = query.orderBy('time_posted', descending: false);
        break;
    }

    print('Final query: ${query.parameters}');

    return query.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      print('Snapshot received. Document count: ${snapshot.docs.length}');
      return snapshot.docs
          .where((doc) => doc['post_user'] == currentUserDisplayName)
          .map((doc) {
        print('Processing document: ${doc.id}');

        return UserPosts2Record.fromSnapshot(doc);
      }).toList();
    });
  }

and the widget where its used
   AuthUserStreamWidget(
                  builder: (context) => SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: StreamBuilder<List<UserPosts2Record>>(
                      stream: _buildFilteredStream(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        // Handle loading state
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }

                        // Handle error state
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Center(
                              child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                        }

                        // Handle empty data
                        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                          return const Center(child: Text('No videos found'));
                        }

                        List<UserPosts2Record> videos = snapshot.data!;

                        // Debug print
                        print('Number of videos: ${videos.length}');

                        return GridView.builder(
                          gridDelegate:
                              const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                          ),
                          itemCount: videos.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final video = videos[index];

                            // Debug print
                            print(
                                'Video at index $index: ${video.postshortDescription}');

                            return VideoCard(video: video);
                          },
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                )

i was trying to sort the results of query for english and tamil and i got error says string is not subtype of documentreference<object?>? in type cast
